# OpenLDAP: Setting up SSL: Implementation specific error

Tags: ssl, openldap, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to set up an SSL certificate that I received from Let's Encrypt. I have the 4 files from LE:

- cert.pem
- chain.pem
- fullchain.pem
- privkey.pem

Following some tutorials, I made sure that `ldap` user has read access to these files, copied them anywhere I saw fit, but nothing really works. All I get every time is `ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)`

I tried creating a dozen kind of .ldif file to try and configure the SSL, all of them eventually threw the error message above.

The lates configuration I tried is this:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/pki/tls/cert.pem
-
delete: olcTLSCACertificatePath
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/pki/tls/private/privkey.pem
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/cert.pem
```

The `/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem` files is the one created by copying the `chain.pem` file to a `ca-trust` folder, and extracting the trusted certificates.

Comment: the strangest thing to me is that whatever order, or combination I run these commands, there is always the very same error message

Answer (score 0):

The problem (which I don't fully understand) was with SELinux.

I don't really know what SELinux does apart from making my life harder, but after disabling it, the problem went away.

I, of course, understand the security risk it poses, so I enabled it back and ran the following command as my final solution, which seems to have solved the problem:

```
setsebool -P allow_ypbind=0 authlogin_nsswitch_use_ldap=0
```

I'm open to accepting answers that explain why this solution works, because this is really cloudy for me and I'd like to understand it a bit more deeply.